# email intent on successful sending or keydown methods

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I have a working email intent. further please note that i finish my all previous back activities and restart them on key down.

i have two problems

when user dont send email and press back button my app close down becoz of on pause finish method
when user send email still last activity is not opened.

I think i am making mistake in startactivity for results. is it possible to solve both problem and open previous activity through intent. (in this case Old.class)
any help will be highly appriciated.
my code

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        getdata();

        String message = message
                ;
        final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(
                android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                new String[] { "google@gmail.com" });
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                "subject");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."),1);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Intent Act2Intent = new Intent(New.this, Old.class);
        startActivity(Act2Intent);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            Intent Act2Intent = new Intent(New.this, Older.class);
            startActivity(Act2Intent);
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStop(this);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not `finish()` the activity `onPause()` as [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html) says pause() comes after on stop(). If you finish() on onPause() then onStop() will not working at all. check the android [activity life-cycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html).

So you can try like this:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
if(!isActivate)
    finish();
}
```

else remove `finish();` from `onPause(){}`.

Comment: still i am facing issue of looping between older activities. to explain it further i have Activity1 -> Activity2 -> Activity3 -> Activity4 -> Activity5 -> send mail. user can go back to activity4 by keydown and again come back to activity5 and send mail. further it creates two/multiple copies of activity4 and user has to press back key to close the activity. i want activity to be available only one time. i got this working by using onpause finish call. but as i stated earlier e-mail intent throws me out of app and as i finished all activites i am out of app.

Comment: Add the following when before starting the activity -`intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_ CLEAR_TOP); `